# Copy first letter of each word in a line

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I would like to copy the first letters of paper titles in a bib file and set that as entry name.
Example:

```
@article{Cqmdoprbcc,
  title={Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete?},
  author={Einstein, Albert and Podolsky, Boris and Rosen, Nathan},
  journal={Physical review},
  volume={47},
  number={10},
  pages={777},
  year={1935},
  publisher={APS}
}
```

Notice that the bibtex entry, `Cqmdoprbcc`, is the first letters of each word in the title.

I am clueless as how to do it and I was hoping I could learn from masters of vim here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your initial text looks like this:

```
@article{some name,
  title={Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete?},
  author={Einstein, Albert and Podolsky, Boris and Rosen, Nathan},
  journal={Physical review},
  volume={47},
  number={10},
  pages={777},
  year={1935},
  publisher={APS}
}
```

Then you could try this substitution command:

```
%s/^\s*@article{\zs.*\ze,/\=substitute(matchstr(getline(search('^\s*title=', 'nW')), '{\zs.\{-}\ze}'), '\(\k\)\k*\%(\k\@!.\)*', '\1', 'g')/
```

If you execute it in your file, it should look for all the lines starting with `@article{` and replace the following name with the first letter of each word on the next line beginning with `title=`.
IOW, it should perform the following substitution:

```
@article{some name,
  title={Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete?},
→
@article{Cqmdoprbcc,
  title={Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete?},
```

---

The syntax of this substitution is:

```
%s/pat/\=expr/
│  │   ├┘│
│  │   │ └ the expression to be evaluated
│  │   │
│  │   └ replace it by the evaluation of the following expression
│  │     (see `:h :s\=`)
│  │
│  └ every time you find a first occurrence of the pattern
│    described by the string 'pat' on a line
│
└ operate on all the lines of the file
```

Here the pattern is:

```
^\s*@article{\zs.*\ze,
│├┘│├───────┘├─┘││├─┘│
││ ││        │  │││  └ the text `,`
││ ││        │  │││
││ ││        │  ││└ look for everything I will describe afterwards,
││ ││        │  ││  but don't replace it when doing the substitution (`:h \ze`)
││ ││        │  ││
││ ││        │  │└ as many as possible
││ ││        │  │
││ ││        │  └ any character (from the old entry name) (`:h /.`)
││ ││        │
││ ││        └ look for everything I've described thus far,
││ ││          but don't replace it when doing the substitution (`:h /\zs`)
││ ││
││ │└ the text `@article{`
││ │
││ └ as many as possible (`:h /*`)
││
│└ a whitespace (`:h /\s`)
│
└ a beginning of line (see `:h /^`)
```

And the expression is:

```
substitute(matchstr(getline(search('^\s*title=', 'nW')), '{\zs.\{-}\ze}'), '\(\k\)\k*\%(\k\@!.\)*', '\1', 'g')
```

The evaluation of `search('^\s*title=', 'nW')` is the numerical address of the next line (relative to where `:s` command is performing a substitution at the moment) described by the pattern `^\s*title=`. IOW, it's the address of the next line beginning with `title=`. Let's call it `S`.
During the evaluation of `S`, the cursor won't move because of the `n` flag passed in the 2nd argument (`:h search()`).

Using the `S` symbol, the expression can be re-written like this:

```
substitute(matchstr(getline(S), '{\zs.\{-}\ze}'), '\(\k\)\k*\%(\k\@!.\)*', '\1', 'g')
```

The evaluation of `getline(S)` is a string, matching the contents of the next line beginning with `title=` (`:h getline()`).
Let's call it `G`.
Using the `G` symbol, the expression can be re-written like this:

```
substitute(matchstr(G, '{\zs.\{-}\ze}'), '\(\k\)\k*\%(\k\@!.\)*', '\1', 'g')
```

The evaluation of `matchstr(G, '{\zs.\{-}\ze}')` is a substring of the previous string. Let's call it `M`. More specifically, it's the part between 2 CONSECUTIVE (because you used the LAZY quantifier `\{-}`, instead of the greedy `*`; see `:h /\{-`) curly brackets.

Using the `M` symbol, the expression can be re-written like this:

```
substitute(M, '\(\k\)\k*\%(\k\@!.\)*', '\1', 'g')
```

The evaluation of this last expression is what you want, i.e. the first letter of each word in your original title.

You could re-write it like this:

```
substitute(M, pat, rep, 'g')
```

Where `pat` is a pattern that `substitute()` has to look for, here `\(\k\)\k*\%(\k\@!.\)*`, and `rep` is the replacement string, here `\1`.

The pattern can be broken down like this:

```
\(\k\)\k*\%(\k\@!.\)*
├────┘├─┘├──────────┘
│     │  └ a sequence of NON-keyword characters, as long as possible (see `:h /\@!`)
│     │
│     └ a sequence of other keyword characters, as long as possible
│
└ look for a keyword character (`:h /\k`), and remember it (`:h /\(`)
```

The replacement string is special, and not a literal string. `\1` refers to the first capturing group in your pattern, which here is the first keyword character of every word in your original title (`:h /\1`).

---

You could also turn it into a custom command (`:SetEntryName`):

```
com! -bar -range=% SetEntryName  call s:set_entry_name(<line1>, <line2>)

fu! s:set_entry_name(line1, line2) abort
    let range = a:line1.','.a:line2
    exe range.'s/^\s*@article{\zs.*\ze,/\=s:get_entry_name()/'
endfu

fu! s:get_entry_name() abort
    let entry = getline(search('^\s*title=', 'nW'))
    let entry = matchstr(entry, '{\zs.\{-}\ze}')
    let entry = substitute(entry, '\(\k\)\k*\%(\k\@!.\)*', '\1', 'g')
    return entry
endfu
```

The command accepts a range, thus works on a visual selection.

Comment: Thank you very much. The entry name is not blank by default though. How do you suggest that I delete the entry to bring it to the format so I can apply your code? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Ali I edited the answer to support lines looking like this: `@article{some name,`. If the code doesn't work, knowing the exact form of the original text would help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like a charm. If you get a chance, would you mind explaining how it works? Especially the regex part. Thanks.

Comment: Hats off to you. You deserve 1000000 upvotes. Thank you very much. I learned a lot :)